# How to reference a table's "Total Row" value from another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm using Excel as part of Office 365 for Enterprise.

I have a budget/finance spreadsheet with the following tabs:

- A tab for each account
- A "dashboard" tab with current balances from each account

The data on each account tab is in a table with a total row.
Each tab's table has a "Payment or Charge" column that is summed in the table's total row

How do I reference that "Payment or Charge" sum value from the dashboard tab?

I tried the following:

ATTEMPT #1:

```
=sum(RegisterAlaskaVisa[Payment or Charge])
```

This works, but is it the right way? It seems that I'm adding up thousands of rows when that's already being done on the account tab. Therefore, this seems inefficient to add all the rows again.

ATTEMPT #2:

```
=RegisterAlaskaVisa[@[Payment or Charge]]
```

This seems produces a value that is not the sum. I have no idea how this value is being computed.

ATTEMPT #3:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,RegisterAlaskaVisa[@[Payment or Charge]])
```

This seems to be what the total row is using, but yields the same incorrect value as ATTEMPT #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference that row/column, use something like:

```
=myTable[[#Totals],[payment or charge]]
```

Note the double brackets and the comma in the structure.